# Is is possible to write cache in application for cluster enviroment?

Tags: java, caching, jakarta-ee, jboss, cluster-computing

I know there are cache products supporting cluster, JBoss Cache etc.

But the JBoss Cache only works for JBoss server and it's not application-level component. 
Is it possible to write own cache for cluster in my application? Each application instance cannot know other instances in cluster, is it true?

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked [infinispan](http://www.jboss.org/infinispan)? It's from JBoss too, but it has an api to control it programatically. To be clear, you don't need to run JBoss, you just need to add the infinispan jar in your app.

Answer (score 0):

In a few words: [terracotta](http://www.terracotta.org).
Brilliant solution. Works fantastically, good support on the forums. Good error messages.
No source footprint, it's all a matter of configuration. Tc will instrument your code with bytecode needed to communicate with the tc server.

Backside: is hub and spoke design. Needs a designated terracotta server.

Comment: I'd like to add the JBossCache doesn't seem to be under active development anymore, thank god. I've used it quite a bit and it was lousy.

Comment: In JBoss 6, Infinispan replaced JBossCache. http://community.jboss.org/wiki/InfinispanIntegrationinAS6